# error: package com.google.maps.android.kml does not exist

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, kml

hi i`m using android studio and there is a new error that i see[image]

i`ve used its package in my Gradle:

```
dependencies {

    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.java-websocket:java-websocket:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu:1.5.4'
    compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk-1.4.jar')
    compile(name: 'signalr-client-sdk-android-release-1.4', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:viewpagerindicator:2.4.3'
}
```

and i have tried all they ways that people said for missing package

i tried "File->invalidate cache/...."

tried updating sdk

tried cleaning and rebuild

tried deleting all "iml" files and deleting .idea folder

tried reordering dependencies

tried using "optimize imports on fly" and "add unambiguous imports on fly"

none of them worked

i need help

**Edit 1:**

and btw this error has shown itself recently. it was fine and working until 2 days ago. and suddenly this error came up

about 2 days ago.

Comment: Try to change your google play services version to the recent version. version 6 is very old

Comment: @NayraAhmed: nope. didnt work

Comment: After some searching, I found that link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/
so try to add this to your gradle 
'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'

Comment: @NayraAhmed thanks friend but i had a 4+ version of this in my Gradle so nope. didnt help. thanks any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the import to:

`import com.google.maps.android.data.kml.KmlLayer;`

The `KmlLayer` class moved in the v0.5 release.

I'd also suggest removing the `+` in your `compile` statement, so it should look like:

`compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'`